# How to reference the current view in a Navigation View Controller

Tags: swift

I have a convince constructor that creates a subview

```
class HudView: UIView {
  var text = ""

  class func hud(inView view: UIView, 
                    animated: Bool) -> HudView {
    let hudView = HudView(frame: view.bounds)
    view.addSubview(hudView)
    
    return hudView
  }
}
```

To use the above and create a view I'm doing the following:

```
let hudView = HudView.hud(inView: navigationController!.view, 
                          animated: true)
```

My question is about referring to the current view and passing it as an argument.  Is this the only way to refer to the current view?  My views are indeed embedded in a Navigation controller, but must I get the current view this way?  I'm following a tutorial.
Thanks!

Comment: You are asking way too many questions. Can you ask **one** per post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From current view I assume you mean the `view` of the `ViewController` currently visible in the `navigationController`.

You can get the currently visible `view` like so,

```
if let view = navigationController?.viewControllers.first?.view {
    let hudView = HudView.hud(inView: view, animated: true)
}
```

And, if you're writing this code in the currently visible `ViewController`, you can simply use `self.view` instead.

```
let hudView = HudView.hud(inView: self.view, animated: true)
```

Comment: If I have a view embedded in a navigation controller, is that view a subview of the nav controller?

Comment: you embed view controllers in the navigation controller and not just the view.

Comment: One last question here?  I want to create a sub view that covers the View Controller view and the Navigation bar above it.  That is what is confusing me.  What view is the Navigation Bar in (Back button, Title, Done button). Thanks!  Does the Navigation Controller have a view?

Comment: Navigation controller embeds view controller which has a view in it. Navigation controller is kind of just a container. So add your view inside the view controller.

Comment: I finally got it.  Thanks!